# Crossing a river with bonds and beefs

Tags: strategy, river-crossing

Here is a river crossing puzzle *(note that whenever I use the term "colors", I mean the squares)*:

---

Yellow and Red are on one side of the river, while Pink, Blue, Green and Black are on the other side. 
There is a singe boat that can hold at most 2 colors on the side where there are four colors.

Some of the colors have bonds and/or beefs with other colors.

Here are all the color's requirements:

- Yellow won't go with Black
- Red will only go alone
- Pink will only go if Yellow is going
- Blue won't go with Green, and will only go if Yellow is going
- Green will go without any conditions
- Black won't go alone and won't go with any of Yellow and Blue.

Here is an example where I bring the colors across in a total of 9 trips:

[image]

#### Find a way to bring all the colors to the opposite sides of the river in under 9 boat trips.

I programmed the tool in the above example.
You can find the tool [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7050/70545).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following would work (8 trips)

> 1. Green crosses alone.
>  2. Yellow comes back alone.
>  3. Yellow crosses with Blue.
>  4. Yellow comes back alone.
>  5. Yellow crosses with Pink.
>  6. Yellow and Green come back.
>  7. Green and Black cross.
>  8. Red comes back alone.